# nginx: setting a specific path to different server

Tags: nginx

I have a single domain name from my university, where I have a service running:

```
    server {
    listen              443 default_server ssl;
    server_name         example.uni.com;
    keepalive_timeout   70;

    ssl_certificate     xxx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key xxx.key;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


}
```

What I would like to achieve, is to have the `example.uni.com/specificaddress` point to a different service running on a different localhost port, without having to modify the service running on 8081 (even nicer would be a `specificaddress.example.uni.com`, but I believe I cannot do that myself). How would this be possible? Simple creating another server with `server_name` set to `example.uni.com/specificaddress` doesn't work unfortunately (not a big suprise, it is handled by the service running on 8081).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a new location block with the proxy pass the different port.

**Example**

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /specificaddress {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```